# Spring : Returning to index page after submitting the details

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, boot

I was trying to work on spring boot.

I created and a form and after submitting it , i have to return to index page. But i am getting error:

```
****Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Oct 18 20:48:04 IST 2022**
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).**
```

I used the following code:

```
@PostMapping("/addStudent")
    String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Students student, Model model) {
        
        studentsRepository.save(student);

        return "index";
    }
```

What is the problem here, what changes do i need to make??

Comment: Do you have template named index? Also you want to go back to index page url (/) ?

Comment: Yes , i have index page